# What is the correct way to include Resource file path in C language?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, filepath

I'm trying to add the file paths of **`Resource Files`** folder in **C**,

[image]

I've tried the following code,

```
char *ResourceFiles[] = {"ResourceFiles\\File-1.bmp", "ResourceFiles\\File-2.bmp", "ResourceFiles\\File-3.bmp"};
```

But I'm just wondering if this is correct or not, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks for your time..:)

Comment: Looks as you're using an ide that groups the files of your project to different categories. These might not be related to any filesystem locations. Please add more information about the environment you are using. (By the way, the "Path" in your screenshot has a whitespace between Resource and Files)

Comment: Visual Studio 2010, Win32 Console Application.

Comment: The c program does not know anything about your ide, so the path has to be the path the files are in in your filesystem (relative to the working directory or absolute)

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ResourceFiles[] = {"ResourceFiles\\File-1.bmp", "ResourceFiles\\File-2.bmp", "ResourceFiles\\File-3.bmp"};
```

init array of pointer to string but when you want to display these strings use this to check :

```
 printf("\n [%s]\n", *ResourceFiles); // first string 
 printf("\n [%s]\n", *(ResourceFiles+1)); // second string 
 printf("\n [%s]\n", *(ResourceFiles+2)); //
 .....
```